# Featuretools documentation of specifying primitive options is wrong?

Tags: featuretools

[The documentation](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/guides/specifying_primitive_options.html) says:

> **Specifying for Individual Primitives**

> Options for individual primitives or groups of primitives are set by the primitive_options parameter of DFS. This parameter maps any desired options to specific primitives. In the case of conflicting options, options set at this level will override options set at the entire DFS run level, and the **include options will always take priority over their ignore counterparts**.

However, I see that this is not true and the ignore option actually takes precedence over the include counterpart.

Below is the set-up I will use to demonstrate the claimed behaviour. It is an entityset with one grandparent (gp), two parents (p1,p2) and one child (c) to one parent (p1):

```
import pandas as pd
import featuretools as ft
from featuretools import variable_types as vt

# # Creating Relational Dataset
# ## Grand Parent 
df_gp = pd.DataFrame({'gp_ind':['a','b'],
                     'gp_ncol1':[1,2],'gp_ncol2':[3,4],
                     'gp_ccol1':['x','y'],'gp_ccol2':['p','q'],
                    'gp_time_col1':pd.to_datetime(['20-01-2020','20-01-2019']),
                    'gp_time_ind':pd.to_datetime(['20-01-2021','20-01-2020'])})

# ## Parent 1
df_p1 = pd.DataFrame({'p1_ind':['a1','a2','b1'],
                     'p1_id': ['a','a','b'],
                     'p1_ncol1':[1,2,3],'p1_ncol2':[3,4,5],
                     'p1_ccol1':['x','y','z'],'p1_ccol2':['p','q','r'],
                      'p1_id1' : ['t','t','u'],
                    'p1_time_col1':pd.to_datetime(['16-01-2020','11-12-2019','16-01-2019'],format="%d-%m-%Y"),
                    'p1_time_ind':pd.to_datetime(['15-01-2021','10-12-2020','15-01-2020'],format="%d-%m-%Y")})

# ## Parent 2
df_p2 = pd.DataFrame({'p2_ind':['a1_','a2_','b1_'],
                     'p2_id': ['a','a','b'],
                     'p2_ncol1':[1,2,3],'p2_ncol2':[3,4,5],
                     'p2_ccol1':['x','y','z'],'p2_ccol2':['p','q','r'],
                    'p2_time_col1':pd.to_datetime(['18-01-2020','13-12-2019','18-01-2019'],format="%d-%m-%Y"),
                    'p2_time_ind':pd.to_datetime(['17-01-2021','12-12-2020','17-01-2020'],format="%d-%m-%Y")})

# ## Child 
df_c = pd.DataFrame({'c_ind':['a1_1','a1_2','a2_1','a2_2','a2_3','b1_1'],
                     'c_id': ['a1','a1','a2','a2','a2','b1'],
                     'c_ncol1':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'c_ncol2':[3,4,5,6,7,8],
                     'c_ccol1':['x','y','z','a','b','c'],'c_ccol2':['p','q','r','s','t','u'],
                    'c_time_col1':pd.to_datetime(['13-01-2020','10-12-2019','8-12-2019','5-11-2019','2-10-2019','13-01-2019'],format="%d-%m-%Y"),
                    'c_time_ind':pd.to_datetime(['10-01-2021','5-12-2020','9-12-2020','6-11-2020','3-10-2019','12-01-2020'],format="%d-%m-%Y")})

# # Creating Entityset
es = ft.EntitySet(id='experimentation')

# ## Adding entities
# ### Adding gp
vt_gp = {'gp_ind':vt.Index,
        'gp_ncol1':vt.Numeric,
        'gp_ncol2':vt.Numeric,
        'gp_ccol1':vt.Categorical,
        'gp_ccol2':vt.Categorical,
        'gp_time_col1':vt.Datetime,
        'gp_time_ind':vt.DatetimeTimeIndex}
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id='gp',dataframe=df_gp,index='gp_ind',variable_types=vt_gp,
                time_index='gp_time_ind')

# ### Adding p1 
vt_p1 = {'p1_ind':vt.Index,
        'p1_id':vt.Id,
        'p1_id1' : vt.Id,
        'p1_ncol1':vt.Numeric,
        'p1_ncol2':vt.Numeric,
        'p1_ccol1':vt.Categorical,
        'p1_ccol2':vt.Categorical,
        'p1_time_col1':vt.Datetime,
        'p1_time_ind':vt.DatetimeTimeIndex}
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id='p1',dataframe=df_p1,index='p1_ind',variable_types=vt_p1,
                time_index='p1_time_ind')

# ### Adding p2
vt_p2 = {'p2_ind':vt.Index,
        'p2_id':vt.Id,
        'p2_ncol1':vt.Numeric,
        'p2_ncol2':vt.Numeric,
        'p2_ccol1':vt.Categorical,
        'p2_ccol2':vt.Categorical,
        'p2_time_col1':vt.Datetime,
        'p2_time_ind':vt.DatetimeTimeIndex}
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id='p2',dataframe=df_p2,index='p2_ind',variable_types=vt_p2,
                time_index='p2_time_ind')

# ### Adding c
vt_c = {'c_ind':vt.Index,
        'c_id':vt.Id,
        'c_ncol1':vt.Numeric,
        'c_ncol2':vt.Numeric,
        'c_ccol1':vt.Categorical,
        'c_ccol2':vt.Categorical,
        'c_time_col1':vt.Datetime,
        'c_time_ind':vt.DatetimeTimeIndex}
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id='c',dataframe=df_c,index='c_ind',variable_types=vt_c,
                time_index='c_time_ind')

# ## Adding Relationships
r_gp_p1 = ft.Relationship(es['gp']['gp_ind'],es['p1']['p1_id'])
r_gp_p2 = ft.Relationship(es['gp']['gp_ind'],es['p2']['p2_id'])
r_p1_c = ft.Relationship(es['p1']['p1_ind'],es['c']['c_id'])
es.add_relationships([r_gp_p1,r_gp_p2,r_p1_c])

# ## Create Cutoff Times
cutoff_times = df_gp.loc[:,['gp_ind','gp_time_ind']].copy(deep=True)

# ## add interesting values
es['p1']['p1_ccol1'].interesting_values = es['p1'].df['p1_ccol1'].unique()[0:1]
es['c']['c_ccol1'].interesting_values = es['c'].df['c_ccol1'].unique()[0:1]

# ## Add last time index 
es.add_last_time_indexes()

# ## Plotting entityset 
es.plot()
```

Now on this entityset I run the following `dfs`:

I include `p1` in both `ignore_entities` and `include_entities` keys. This way, I convey conflicting commands to `dfs` about whether or not to include `p1` entity in the feature creation process.

**Expected behaviour:** `include_entities` to override `ignore_entities` and variables on entity `p1` should be made

**Behaviour seen:** `ignore_entities` overrides `include_entities` and variables on `p1` are not made

```
agg_primitives = ['sum']
where_primitives = ['sum']

primitive_options = {}
primitive_options[('sum',)] = {}

primitive_options[('sum',)]['ignore_entities'] = ['p1'] 
primitive_options[('sum',)]['include_entities'] = ['p1'] 

features = ft.dfs(entityset=es,target_entity='gp', cutoff_time=cutoff_times,
                  agg_primitives=agg_primitives,features_only=True,max_depth=2,
                  where_primitives = where_primitives,
primitive_options=primitive_options,trans_primitives=[])

features

output:
[<Feature: gp_ncol1>,
 <Feature: gp_ncol2>,
 <Feature: gp_ccol1>,
 <Feature: gp_ccol2>]
```

**No feature made on `p1` which goes against what is stated in the documentation**

Am I missing something here or is the documentation actually wrong as I see it and I should understand that `ignore_entities` overrides `include_entities`

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug, you can track the proposed fix here: https://github.com/alteryx/featuretools/pull/1518